# ansible cannot access a variable from ansible vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I am trying to setup Jenkins job calling ansible-playbook. There is an issue with

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'my_vault', variable: 'VAULT_TOKEN')]){
    ansiblePlaybook(
        // ...
        playbook: 'clusterControl.yml',
        inventory: 'inventories/${env.Stand}/hosts',
        extras: " ${ansible_log_level} --ssh-extra-args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --vault-password-file '${VAULT_TOKEN}'")}
```

clusterControl.yml has the following content:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ domain | default('stand') }}"
  strategy: free
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - "inventories/{{ stand }}/bh_vault.yml"
  roles:
    - { role: 03_clusterControl, when: ' "win" in (group_names | string) ' }
    - { role: 03_clusterControl_linux, when: ' "lin" in (group_names | string) ' }
```

`bh_vault.yml` is file encrypted with `ansible-vault encrypt` with password from `VAULT_TOKEN` containing these lines

```
bh:
  ip: "ip.of.my.server"
  username: "my_username"
  password: "my_p@ssw0rd"
```

When I run it Jeninks fails with

```
  fatal: [str-vst-was0012]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The field 'remote_user' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'bh' is undefined\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'bh' is undefined"}

  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
  str-vst-was0012            : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

How to pass bh.ip to ansible?

Comment: Where in your command are you defining that `{{ stand }}` var that could allow it to load the `vars_file` you're expecting?

Comment: I pass {{stand}} as a variable in Jenkins "build with variables".